# Find column by value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

```
class Child
  has_many :toys
end


class Toys
  belongs_to :child
end

class CreateToys < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
def change
  create_table :toys do |t|
  t.integer :child_id
  t.boolean :marbles, default: false
  t.boolean :blocks,  default: false
  t.boolean :jacks,   default: false
  t.boolean :dolls,   default: false
  t.timestamps
  end
 end
end

child = Child.first
child.toys.create(marbles=true, blocks=true, jacks=false, dolls=false)
```

How do I perform a query to return the toys for which the child has as true?
I do not want to have to use the column names in the query so that I can add toys to the list and be able to find any marked as true without having to specify each.

Comment: can you explain this with an example "I do not want to have to use the column names in the query so that I can add toys to the list and be able to find any marked as true without having to specify each."

Comment: I don't think that this data model makes very much sense. Have to add a column to a table every time you think of a new type of toy isn't very nice. What's wrong with just have a string column `toy_type`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
toy_attributes = Toy.new.attributes.keys.select do |key| 
  key != 'created_at' && key != 'updated_at' 
end
params = toy_attributes.reduce({}) do |params, attr| 
  params[attr] = true; params 
end
toys = params.flat_map do |attribute, value| 
  child.toys.where({attribute => value})
end
```